# Where to save files from Firefox add-on?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am working on a Firefox add-on which among other stuff generates thumbnails of websites for use by the add-on. So far I've been storing them by their image data URL using simple-storage. Two problems with this: the storage space is limited and sending very long strings around doesn't seem optimal(I assume the browser has optimized ways of loading image files, but maybe not data URLs). I think it shouldn't be a problem to save the files to disk, the question is where though. I googled quite a bit and could not find anything. Is there a natural place for this? Are there any restrictions?

Comment: Simple storage saves to `{fx_profile_folder}/jetpack/{your_addon_id}/simplete-stroage/something.json` So preferable you should also save stuff to that same folder, because on uninstall of your addon that folder gets deleted, which is good because you dont want to leave traces on your users computers after uninstall.

Comment: Or not: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627432 Do reviewers/anybody actually care where files end up? I've seen add-ons saving files into something like {fx_profile_folder}/{your_addon_id}. I can actually hook into the shutdown(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload) and cleanup after myself, so that should not be a problem...

Comment: Nice find, I manually delete my files on uninstall anyways. Store it wherever, just clean it up on uninstall I say.

Answer (score 0):

As of [Firefox 32](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/08/14/compatibility-for-firefox-32/), the place to store data for your add-on is supposed to be: `[profile]/extension-data/[add-on ID]`. This was established by the resolution of "[Bug 915838 - Provide add-ons a standard directory to store data, settings](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=915838)". There is a follow-on bug, "[Bug 952304 - (JSONStore) JSON storage API for addons to use in storing data and settings](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=952304)" which is supposed to provide an API for easy access.

For the Addon-SDK, you can obtain the addon ID (which you define in *package.json*) with:

```
let self = require("sdk/self");
let addonID = self.id;
```

For XUL and restartless extensions, you should be able to get the ID of your addon (which you define in the *install.rdf* file) with:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
let addonID = Services.appInfo.ID
```

You can then do the following to generate a URI for a file in that directory:

```
userProfileDirectoryPath = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                                     .getService( Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
                                     .get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile).path,

/**
 * Generate URI for a filename in the extension's data directory under the preferences
 *   directory.
 */
function generateURIForFileInPrefExtensionDataDirectory (fileName) {
    //Account for the path separator being OS dependent
    let toReturn = "file://" + userProfileDirectoryPath.replace(/\\/g,"/");

    return toReturn +"/extension-data/" + addonID + "/" + fileName;
    }
}
```

The object `myExtension.addonData` is a copy that I store of the [Bootstrap data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Bootstrap_data) provided to entry points in [*bootstrap.js*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions#Bootstrap_entry_points).