# Avoid signed extenstion being disabled by Firefox when extension stores settings

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to store some user settings in a file "abc.text" in a local folder "abc" inside the extension using [nsILocalFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsILocalFile). But, every time the extension saves the file, Firefox notifies that my extension is not verified and then disables my extension. Maybe saving the file to the extension directory changed its signature. So, how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Storing dynamic data files for an extension:**
Once signed, all files in your extension directory, `[profileDir]/extensions`, have a signature that has been generated by Mozilla.  Those signatures are stored in the files contained in `[profileDir]/extensions/META-INF`. Within your extension directory, any changes to the files, any additional files, or removing any files will result in invalidating the extension signature. If the signature is invalidated, and the Firefox you are using *requires* extensions to be signed your extension will be disabled. (See answer to "[Signing XUL-based add-on for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33929935/3773011)" for list of differences between Firefox versions and alternatives available for add-on development.)

The solution to this is that you need to store your data in a directory that is outside your extension directory. As of [Firefox 32](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/08/14/compatibility-for-firefox-32/), the place to store data for your add-on is supposed to be: `[profile]/extension-data/[add-on ID]`.

For more detailed information regarding this directory, including code to generate a URI for files with the directory, see my answer to the question: "[**Where to save files from Firefox add-on?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32917842/3773011)"

**Storing extension settings (preferences):**
For simple, or even moderately complex, user settings the "normal" place to store those is in [Firefox preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences). For XUL and restartless add-ons you can see: [Preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences). For the Addon-SDK these are known as [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs). For more information, you can read most, if not all of, the results returned when [searching MDN for preferences](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=&as_qdr=all&q=preferences%20site%3Adeveloper.mozilla.org&oq=preferences%20site%3Adeveloper.mozilla.org).

Using Firefox preferences puts extension settings in the same place as a user expects to see them (`about:addons`, then the options page for each add-on). This keeps a consistent User Interface which users of Firefox expect to see and know how to interact with. It should also result in you having to do less coding to create your own UI design and adopt a extension specific method of storing configuration information.

If you have a large amount of data that the extension needs to store, then you should use an external file, as you are currently attempting to do. How big "large amount of data" actually is has been somewhat nebulously defined.

A note on MDN ([nsIPrefBranch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch#setCharPref%28%29)) says:

> Note: The preferences system is not designed to store large amounts of
>   data: all preferences are stored in a single file, which is read at
>   the application startup. If you find yourself wondering what is the
>   maximum amount of data you can store in a string preference, consider
>   storing data separately, for example in a [flat file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O) or an [sqlite
>   database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage).

Answer (score 1):

Since Firefox 44 you cannot, because of the new rules about signing. If you change an extension, it will be unsigned and then blocked.

1st solution :

- use Firefox developer edition or Firefox 43.
- in about:config, set xpinstall.signatures.required to false.

2nd solution : use a firefox version < 43 or Firefox ESR which doesn't handle signatures at all (for the moment).

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing

If you have a problem with Firefox <43, delete the META-INF directory of the extension which is the signing directory. The extension will be unsigned but not "signed and modified then blocked".