# How to persistently store data in `localStorage` when using `jpm run` for a Firefox Add-on SDK extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-developer-tools

I am working on Firefox extension and I need to store date in `localStorage` for login property.

I used simple storage but simple storage loses data after restart.

So, please let me know how to store data in `localStorage`.

Comment: Simple storage should not be lost after restart because it saves to file, see this post to see how it works - https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/does-simple-storage-work/6724/13?u=noitidart - you must be doing something that is causing it to clear

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please *[edit] the question* to include your source code in the question. StackOverflow is generally for specific questions to solve specific problems, not for general tutorials. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using [`jpm run`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_run) to test your add-on. `jpm run` uses a fresh, temporary profile each time you execute it. If you want any data to persist from one execution to another you will need to use the `-p` or `--profile=` option to specify a profile to use for that run. See [Using profiles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Using_profiles) on MDN. You can specify either the profile name, or the path to the profile. The lack of persistence of just using `jpm run` will be an issue for any storage which is placed in the profile, or profile directory be it a preference with [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs), data using [simple-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage), a file using [io/file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file), a database using [SQLite database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Local_Storage#SQLite), or any other method. This is explicitly stated on multiple pages, including the [simple-storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage#Simple_storage_and_jpm_run) page.

Examples (from MDN):

```
jpm run --profile boogaloo
jpm run --profile path/to/boogaloo
```

If you want to create a new profile to use for testing, you can use the [profile manager](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). You can start the profile manager by starting Firefox with any of the options `-p`, `-P`, or `-ProfileManager`. Normally, you will need to exit out of any currently running Firefox instance in order to start a new version of Firefox. However, it is also possible to start a new instance while having Firefox open with a different profile by using the `-no-remote` option. For example, on 64-bit Windows, to start the Firefox profile manager, I normally use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -ProfileManager
```

If you are really wanting to use local storage, you should store the data within the profile directory, so you will still need to do the above steps to use a specified profile.  You will want to look at [io/file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file), and will need to [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file#open%28path_mode%29) the file and then read or write it using [text-streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_text-streams) or [byte-streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_byte-streams). The next logical question is where it should be stored, but that is another question: [Where to save files from Firefox add-on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32783050/3773011)